# processing fastq files using cellranger on linux

Tags: linux, bash, cellranger

I am trying to perform a cellranger count on fastq files generated from a 10x genomics single cell RNA Seq run.

Just to provide some background, I ssh’d into the AWS using our AWS IP with MobaXTerm linux command line.

My files are in the Isilon. The file folders are `path/to/runs/` - this folder contains the `.fastq` files for each sample (ex: `SI_GA_A1_S1`, `SI_GA_B1_S2`, `SI_GA_C1_S3`, and `SI_GA_D1_S4`). I can see these folders listed in the linux command line.

The cellranger is found when I write the following:

```
path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1
```

then `ls` brings up 13 items located in the folder, one of them being `cellranger`.

When I write the following command,

```
/path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger count \
    --id=run2\
    --transcriptome=/path/to/refseq/refdata-cellranger-hg19-3.0.0\
    --sample=sample1\
    --expect-cells=5000
```

and it gives me:

```
-bash: /path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger: No such file or directory
```

This looks correct from what the 10x website says for single cell RNA Seq. Please advise.

```
$ ls -l /path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger 
-rwxrwx--- 1 1003080 1000000 460 Dec 5 19:41 /path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger
```

Comment: You're using the wrong path. What does  `ls -l /path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger` return? Don't you want `/path/to/cellranger-3.0.1//cellranger` instead?

Comment: @terdon, an ls -l /path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger returns: -rwxrwx--- 1 1003080 1000000 460 Dec  5 19:41 /[insert isilon path here]/[insert windowsID here]/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger.  why do you think it is the wrong path? if I do instead ls -l /path/to/cellranger-3.0.1//cellranger , it gives: ls: cannot access /[insert isilon path here]/[insert windowsID here]/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger: No such file or directory

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add clarifications. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. Use the [formatting tools](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format them as code so we can see what you are running.

Comment: Please try and use consistent paths. This sort of issue is usually caused by a tiny detail, and it's hard to catch when you use both `/path/to/` and `/[insert isilon path here]/[insert windowsID here]`. Also, the output of `ls -l /path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger` seems to have an extra `.` at the end. That isn't actually in your output, right?

Comment: As @terdon said, It's certainly a path problem, but it's really hard to spot given your code formatting.

Comment: hello, I have updated the original post. @terdon, the . at the end is not part of the output. I have updated the original post to contain only /path/to/ if that seems to simplify things. thank you.

Comment: Something is wrong here. The error tells you that `/path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger` doesn't exist, but `ls /path/to/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger` shows the file. Are you 100% _sure_ the paths you are using in your question are correct? Could you show us the real paths used? Are there any spaces in any of the paths? Any capital letters that you've changed to lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

this has been resolved. I downloaded the windows file and this caused trouble but when downloading the file within the Linux, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `cellranger` does not have execute permissions. Try

```
chmod u+x [insert internal isilon path here]/[insert windows username here]/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger-3.0.1/cellranger
```

(or the Windows equivalent, which seems to be to give Execute permission using the GUI)

Comment: I tried this as you wrote and it says permission denied in linux command line. what is the windows equivalent? can I do this permission sharing in the Windows?

Comment: This isn't a permissions issue, the error is about a wrong path. If the file existed but didn't have execute permissions, you would get a `Permission denied` error instead.

Comment: @terdon, I get a Permissions denied error

Comment: From your update, you seem to have the requisite permissions. @terdon Before OP's update, it could have been a permissions issue, and I wanted to ensure that was not the case. OP seems to be on a Windows machine, IDK how permissions work on Windows.

Comment: The OP is connecting to an AWS instance running Linux (according to the question, anyway) and the error messages on Linux are quite specific. If the file exists but isn't executable, you would never get a file not found error.

Comment: Sorry, I was going by windows user name that was in every path. OTOH, there's also the "linux" mentioned in the title and the tags. OP needs to be clearer about this

Comment: @RamRS, the linux AWS instance is mentioned in the 2nd line of my OP

Comment: And the question is tagged with `linux` :)

Comment: @sv1234 "MobaXTerm linux command line" is confusing. Is it MobaXTerm (Windows-only app) or a linux command line interface? Like I said, you need to be clearer.